# Return 0 in Sheets Query if there is no data

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I need some advice in google query language.

I want to count rows depending on date and a condition. But if the condition is not met, it should return 0.

What I'm trying to achieve:

Date        Starts
05.09.2018  0
06.09.2018  3
07.09.2018  0

What I get:

Date        Starts
06.09.2018  3

The query looks like `=Query(Test!$A2:P; "select P, count(B) where (B contains 'starts') group by P label count(B) 'Starts'")`

P contains ascending datevalues and B an event (like start in this case).
How can I force output a 0 for the dates with no entry containing "start"?

The main point is to get all needed data in one table in ascending order. But this is only working, if every day has an entry. If there is no entry for a day, the results for "start" do not match the datevalue in column A. 3 in column D would be in the first row of the table then.

I need it like this:

A           B      C        D
Date        Logins Sessions Starts 
05.09.2018  1      2        0 
06.09.2018  3      4        3
07.09.2018  4      5        0

Maybe this is easy to fix, but I don't see it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pre-processing before the query. Ex: check if column B contains 'start' with regexmatch and use a double unary (--) to force the boolean values into 1's and 0's. The use query to sum.

```
=Query(Arrayformula({--regexmatch(Test!$B2:B; "start")\ Test!$A2:P}); "select Col17, sum(Col1) where Col17 is not null group by Col17 label sum(Col1) 'Starts'")
```

Change ranges to suit.